# Inject a soap response xml from file into the soapclient instead of fetching response from http

Tags: php, soap-client

I am using soapclient and it returns the result as an object. However I want to now inject the soap xml response as there is an issue with the how I parse the objects. How can I inject my soap xml without the soapclient fetching it from the the server? The soap xml response is stored in a file.